# gitlab-ci.yml - before_script - how to only run it in specific stages

Tags: include, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci.yml

I have the following gitlab-ci.yml: (only showing relevant code)

```
stages:
  - unitTest
  - deploy-fn-development
  - deploy-fn-rehearse
  - deploy-fn-prod

include: "/ci_templates/.create-variables.yml"
```

And this is what the include file looks like:

```
default:
  before_script:
    - etc.
```

The code works and creates the variables I need at every stage in the pipeline.  But now  I need to only run the create-variables.yml in rehearse and production stages
Is there a way to do this with the current structure?  or do I have to remove it as a general include and somehow include the create-variables.yml at each specific stage I want to run it?

Thanks

Comment: Look at this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54074433/gitlab-ci-specifying-stages-in-before-script

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can override `before_script` or configure inheritance on a per-job basis.

```yaml
default:
  before_script:
    - echo "default before_script"

some_job:
  # ...
  before_script:
    - echo "overrides before_script"
```

You can also configure whether a job inherits properties from `default:` by using the [`inherit:`](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#inheritdefault) key.

```yaml
some_job:
  inherit:
    default: false  # this job won't inherit any `default:` keys
```

There is no mechanism to apply such changes on a per-stage basis.

Comment: perfect!  thanks for the clear / simple explanation!